# Play 2.2 publish-local default folder

Tags: playframework-2.0, repository, publish

I have two Play Application developed in Java using Play 2.2.0.

- my-app-commons
- my-app-api

I want to create a dependency for my-app-commons in my-app-api so I want to publish locally the first application.
I execute the following command :

`play publish-local`

But the problem is that the result does not respect the structure described in the documentation.
I have

> /play-to-path/repository/local/default/my-app-commons_2.10/1.0.0/poms/my-app-commons_2.10.pom

instead of

> /play-to-path/repository/local/my-app-commons/my-app-commons_2.10/1.0.0/poms/my-app-commons_2.10.pom

How can I fix this ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the organization in your build.sbt file.  I have the following:

name := "playcommon"

organization := "com.ericsson.ilab"

version := "1.0"